# Conditional grouped iteration over a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| user | event_id | event_creation | event_b | USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2021/07/01 | NaN | 10 |
| a | 2 | 2021/07/02 | 2021/07/17 | 10 |
| a | 3 | 2021/07/22 | 2021/08/02 | 10 |
| a | 4 | 2021/07/24 | 2021/08/02 | 10 |
| a | 5 | 2021/07/24 | 2021/08/06 | 10 |
| a | 6 | 2021/08/16 | 2021/01/29 | 10 |
| b | 7 | 2021/08/18 | 2021/10/14 | 10 |

I want to create a new column based on a conditional aggregated sum_cum. 
Grouped by user, iterate over the event_ids, 
For each event_id look at all previous events and sum the USD amount of all the events in which the event_b date is smaller than the current event's creation date.
So i will get the following DataFrame:

| user | event_id | event_creation | event_b | USD | sum_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2021/07/01 | NaN | 10 | 0 |
| a | 2 | 2021/07/02 | 2021/07/17 | 10 | 0 |
| a | 3 | 2021/07/22 | 2021/08/02 | 10 | 10 |
| a | 4 | 2021/07/24 | 2021/08/02 | 10 | 10 |
| a | 5 | 2021/07/24 | 2021/08/06 | 10 | 10 |
| a | 6 | 2021/08/16 | 2021/01/29 | 10 | 40 |
| b | 7 | 2021/08/18 | 2021/10/14 | 10 | 0 |

I tried to create loops but didn't bare any fruits, i hope the explanation is clear, thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.apply(
    lambda x: df[
        (df.event_b < x.event_creation) &
        (df.event_id < x.event_id) &
        (df.user == x.user)
    ].USD.sum(),
    axis=1)
```

You can also use `groupby` instead of `df.user == x.user`

If you have a very large dataset it might become slow, since you are slicing the df for each row.